# reading data via PDO - the same row is brought twice

Tags: php, sql-server

I read rows from some mssql table via PHPs PDO.

Some rows, are brought twice, exactly same rows, with exactly the same *id* values

- This happens to specific rows. Each time I run my import script, the issue happens on the very same rows. For example, after bringing some 16,000 rows correctly, one row, the same one each time, is brought twice.
- The duplication occurs in a row. The line is brought, and the next fetch() request returns the very same row.
- When I run:
   select * from MY_TABLE where id='the problematic id'
  only one row is returned, not two

Any ideas what (the hell) can go on here?

Thank you very much guys

edit:
The query that is being run:

```
select o.accountid, c.contactid, o.opportunityid, o.createdate, o.modifydate, o.createuser, o.modifyuser, o.description, o.projclosedate, o.notes, o.accountmanagerid 
from sysdba.opportunity o 
left join sysdba.opportunity_contact oc on o.opportunityid = oc.opportunityid and oc.salesrole = 'speaker' ";
left join sysdba.contact c on c.contactid = oc.contactid 
where o.status <> 'Inactive' 
order by o.opportunityid asc;
```

Comment: Probably you have some rows multiplication. Post the exact query you perform.

Comment: You have a wrong join somewhere - please post the query that is used to retrieve the rows..

Comment: Well, here it is (above)

Comment: This is going to return all non-inactive records from "opportunity". Is that what you want?

Comment: Also, you might want to put "o.status <> 'Inactive" as part of both those join conditions

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to join your `contact` table to your `opportunity` table. It seems that you might not have a 1 to 1 mapping between those tables the way you have it set up. See below:

```
--This should reference the "o" table but it doesn't.
left join sysdba.contact c on c.contactid = oc.contactid
```

If that's not the case then you should really be joining around the `opportunity_contact` table instead (put it as your 'from' table).

Comment: This is what I'm doing. Or do you mean the order?

Comment: If you can edit your question to paint a better picture of what those tables look like and what you want your results to look like, then I can probably be more helpful